# Picasso not work with 1.bp.blogspot.com url

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I tried to do everything but not working.
I checked the link a thousand times and opened it in the browser and it works well.
But another link works perfectly

Do anyone tell me why this code does not work?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        Picasso.get()
            .load("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-qgZfrkC0FWw/XPWFD8BtcOI/AAAAAAABcs4/S8KFUqFgVtgrmMn5CZ7J8UkKLM1OQ6FVACLcBGAs/s640/Firefox%2BLockwise.jpg")
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(imageView)
    }

}
```

My layout code is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="56dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="56dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="675dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And log:

```
06/04 10:11:44: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk D:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyBlog\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed in 32 s 391 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.alisaki.myblog/com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 31943 on device samsung-sm_j320f-420009d1f0c85400
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
    v2
I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J320F_5.1.1_0072
E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/art: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) failed for pid 31943: Operation not permitted
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10113
    KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.alisaki.myblog-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.alisaki.myblog rsrc of package com.alisaki.myblog
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
    fillFeatureStoreMap com.alisaki.myblog
I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.alisaki.myblog, Feature store :{}
    featureStore :{}
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.alisaki.myblog-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.alisaki.myblog rsrc of package com.alisaki.myblog
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.alisaki.myblog-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.alisaki.myblog rsrc of package com.alisaki.myblog
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080947 (t=7 e=2375) (error -75)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
    *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity isFragment :false
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
    *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/com.alisaki.myblog/cache/picasso-cache/journal.tmp
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
    Enabling debug mode 0
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity
    dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@25ceb117 time:28955475
```

AndroidManifest.xml content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.alisaki.myblog">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? E/Zygote: v2
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10113
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J320F_5.1.1_0072
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-04 10:24:54.753 32201-32201/? E/art: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) failed for pid 32201: Operation not permitted
06-04 10:24:54.803 32201-32208/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
06-04 10:24:54.823 32201-32201/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.alisaki.myblog-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.alisaki.myblog rsrc of package com.alisaki.myblog
06-04 10:24:54.833 32201-32201/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
06-04 10:24:54.843 32201-32201/? D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
06-04 10:24:54.843 32201-32201/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
06-04 10:24:55.474 32201-32201/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-04 10:24:55.474 32201-32201/? D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
06-04 10:24:55.474 32201-32201/? D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.alisaki.myblog
06-04 10:24:55.474 32201-32201/? I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.alisaki.myblog, Feature store :{}
06-04 10:24:55.474 32201-32201/? I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
06-04 10:24:55.594 32201-32201/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.alisaki.myblog-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.alisaki.myblog rsrc of package com.alisaki.myblog
06-04 10:24:55.594 32201-32201/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.alisaki.myblog-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.alisaki.myblog rsrc of package com.alisaki.myblog
06-04 10:24:55.594 32201-32201/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080947 (t=7 e=2375) (error -75)
06-04 10:24:55.644 32201-32201/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-04 10:24:55.734 32201-32201/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
06-04 10:24:55.734 32201-32201/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
06-04 10:24:55.744 32201-32201/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
06-04 10:24:55.744 32201-32201/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
06-04 10:24:56.014 32201-32201/? D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-04 10:24:56.014 32201-32201/? D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-04 10:24:56.194 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
06-04 10:24:56.194 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity isFragment :false
06-04 10:24:56.214 32201-32222/com.alisaki.myblog D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
06-04 10:24:56.224 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
06-04 10:24:56.224 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
06-04 10:24:56.275 32201-32221/com.alisaki.myblog W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/com.alisaki.myblog/cache/picasso-cache/journal.tmp
06-04 10:24:56.285 32201-32222/com.alisaki.myblog I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-04 10:24:56.285 32201-32222/com.alisaki.myblog D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
06-04 10:24:56.285 32201-32222/com.alisaki.myblog D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-04 10:24:56.375 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
06-04 10:24:56.385 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity
06-04 10:24:56.385 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity
06-04 10:24:56.405 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@25ceb117 time:29711119
06-04 10:25:07.716 32201-32201/com.alisaki.myblog V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{369d2259 token=android.os.BinderProxy@25ceb117 {com.alisaki.myblog/com.alisaki.myblog.MainActivity}} show : true
```

Build.gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alisaki.myblog"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0"
    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0"
}
```

Picasso is not provide any log's

Whene I try to use Glide it's not work too. I receive the error in log :

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-qgZfrkC0FWw/XPWFD8BtcOI/AAAAAAABcs4/S8KFUqFgVtgrmMn5CZ7J8UkKLM1OQ6FVACLcBGAs/s640/Firefox%2BLockwise.jpg with size [389x623]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException(No route to host)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException(No route to host)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException(No route to host)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:605)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:104)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:59)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:65)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

I'm Using Samsung J3 6 android Lolipop (API 22)

Sorry for bad English

Comment: Any particular error ?  try to see what’s going on in the logcat

Comment: Hi will you please share me the  log caterror or response

Comment: It worked at mine side.

Comment: Does your app uses pro guard ?

Comment: your solution is here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56438058/7832102

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Give your imageview height and width instead of 0dp and remove constraint layoutlayout.

Add internet permission in your Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I tried and it is working fine with below Picasso version

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have already put a permission and i implement the picasso in build.gradle but it's is not work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok in that case can you share the xml? what are the dimensions of imageview?

Comment: @AliSaki - Give imageview height and width in dp. like 150 dp & 150dp and don't use constraint layout. Lets test if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add internet permission into the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Like.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please use the below method to get your solution.

```
Picasso..with(this)
            .load("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-qgZfrkC0FWw/XPWFD8BtcOI/AAAAAAABcs4/S8KFUqFgVtgrmMn5CZ7J8UkKLM1OQ6FVACLcBGAs/s640/Firefox%2BLockwise.jpg")
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already put a permission but it's is not work. Thanks anyway

Comment: I try to open this image URL in my browser but it takes a long time to load the image.

Comment: wen I try use with method i recived this error : "Unresolved reference: with"

Comment: Loading photos is fast in my browser. I have many pictures in this host so I do not think about cache

Comment: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0 use this library version. @AliSaki

Comment: picasso:2.4.0 There is no difference

Comment: Did you add this version of library?